# What is the fastest way to download source code from a web page in python with proxy?

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, urllib2, scraper

I'm already using urllib2 to get the pages using proxy, but it's taking way too long, and I know that using proxy takes longer, but still is taking too long comparing if I test the proxy in firefox or ie.

Thanks.

Comment: Modern web-browsers use HTTP Pipelining in which they send out multiple requests to ensure quicker load times. You could also try using multiple threads to perform the scraping in parallel. I dont see any relation to the proxy though.

Answer (score 1):

To download pages faster you need to do that concurrently no matter using proxy or not. 
Try gevent library.
There is an example for concurent download https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/concurrent_download.py